# How to pass parameters to bash command in node exec function?

Tags: node.js, child-process, electron

I want to run bash script with params in node js `child_process.exec()`

In doc is `String The command to run, with space-separated arguments`, but

```
child.exec("cat path_to_file1 path_to_file2")
```

doesn't work. It is internally changed to

```
/bin/sh -c cat path_to_file1 path_to_file2
```

which fails. How can I run this correctly? In shell I would fix it this way

```
/bin/sh -c 'cat path_to_file1 path_to_file2'
```

(I didn't write callbacks, because I ask only about command param)

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. `exec("cat file1 file2")` works correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Use the shell option of exec :

```
child.exec("cat path_to_file1 path_to_file2", {
 shell : '/bin/bash' 
})
```

see options : https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback

Comment: Yes, but can be updated . So, you force the shell with the shell option .

Answer (score -1):

Did you tried something like this?

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var child;
child = exec("cat '/route/to/file_a' '/route/to/file_b'", function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(stdout);
    console.log(stderr);
    if (error !== null) {
        console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }
});
```

That way you can find what is wrong or get the correct output. ;)